# No main manifest attribute found in Corda Standalone Shell jar of Corda Enterprise v4.0

Tags: shell, blockchain, corda

I want to evaluate Corda Standalone Shell of Corda Enterprise v4.0.
I have downloaded corda-shell-4.0.jar from below URL
https://www.r3.com/corda-enterprise-download/
And refering to below document
https://docs.corda.r3.com/releases/4.0/shell.html?highlight=standalone%20shell#the-standalone-shell I am analysing the Standalone Shell and when I run `java -jar corda-shell-4.0.jar` command then I get the following error:

```
no main manifest attribute, in corda-shell/corda-shell-4.0.jar
```

When I checked the MANIFEST.MF file then there is no Main-Class specified in the Manifest file.
Can anyone please guide me how to use the standalone shell?

Comment: Have you configed your config-file?

Comment: @PeterLi Yes I have configed my node.conf file

Answer (score 0):

Have a read of this - https://docs.corda.r3.com/releases/4.0/cli-application-shell-extensions.html .

It the jar is not meant to be run via `java -jar`. Instead, you install the CLI commands and need to set up some config to get it all to work.